# How do I reverse/flip/invert/swap scala's Option?

Tags: scala, reverse

Let's say you've got `Option[A]` you need to convert it to
`Some(b : B)` for `None`
and to
`None` for `Some(a : A)`.

Is there code that does this already? I can write some, but what's the most straightforward way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most straightforward way is :

```
val b : B = new B()
val newA: Option[B] = a.fold(Some(b))(_ => None)
```

Comment: `b` should be a plain value and do `Some(b)` on the fold`

Comment: Well it depends on the context... But yes it might be more general

Comment: `def f[A, B](s: Option[A], b: B) = s.fold(Some(b) : Option[B])(_ => None)`

Comment: @galva: `s.fold(Option(b))(_ => None)` for the win.

Comment: Can we use 'match' over here and based on the value & type, produce the new value?

Comment: Of course we can. However this is less straigthforward ;)

Comment: The answer in this current state is wrong. It would not compile because the second parameter list of `fold` is expecting a function from A => B and not a plain value. You should update the answer as per @pedrofurla's comment.